# passing 3D matrix from matlab to c++ through mexfile

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I want to use Mexfile for some operations on 3D matrix, which is to be passed from Matlab and fill some values in it and return the matrix to Matlab.

Can someone help me with this ?

```
 i=1;
 for yc=1:gs:roib-r-3 
  j=1;
   for xc=r+3:gs:roil-r-3 
       for n=1:slength
         sf(n,i,j)=%somevalue;
       end   
    j=j+1;
   end
  i=i+1;
  end
```

Edit: I have put the  code above, i want to perform these forloops in c++ mexfile. But im stuck at passing 3D array as an argument and returning it back in plhs, prhs ?

Comment: what did you try? what is the problem?

Comment: @tobi303 I have edited the question.

Comment: do you want to write a file in matlab, read it in c++, do some calculations, write it to a file again and then read it again in matlab? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Actually , im working on a project of which this is a small part .I was asked to improve runtime , so im trying that with mexfile .

Comment: there is a bit too little context to say something, but I doubt that the strategy you have in mind will improve anything. The file i/o will most likely outweight any improvement you get from running that loop in c++ instead of matlab

Comment: Yeah, but i like to once check that option also if there is any chance in improvement .Also, "%somevalue" is a function which i think if i wrtie it in C++ , will improve the runtime.

Comment: ..ok then it is still not clear what is the problem/quesiton. As I said before, you need to a) write the file in matlab b) read it in c++ c) do the calculation d) write results to file e) read it in matlb. Where are you stuck? If you have no idea where to start at all, then start with a) write a file in matlab, there must be plenty of documentation on that....

Comment: I know how to write in matlab and c++ , the problem is im unable to pass the argument "3D matrix " , from matlab to c++ using "MEX" file. Hope this is clear .Also im not using intermediate files to store results .Im just using two files ,a) Matlab b)Mex file.

Comment: sorry, no it isnt clear. Why are you unable to pass it? You should include a detailed description of what you tried and why it doesnt work in the question.